# Attaching debugger to Android process automatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

Is there any way to configure Android Studio to attach the debugger to an android process automatically (specifically for a background process started by a service)?  I want to have breakpoints stop execution in Android Studio for services that are running in a background process.  I have been able to manually start a started service and attach the debugger manually to get this to work.  I was just wondering if there is someway to configure Android Studio to do this automatically.

**Edit**: I probably should have mentioned first that I wanted to attach the debugger to a background android process created from starting or binding to a service.

Comment: Launching it with debug instead of run

Comment: That seems to only catch breakpoints within the same process as the android application.  I want to catch breakpoints in a service that is running in a separate background process (i.e. manifest has the service's remote attribute set to the name of the process).

Comment: Yes, you need to launch the service with debug as well.

Comment: @DanielAquino Were you able to resolve this?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 20):

If you have the package name, you type `adb shell am set-debug-app -w packagename` to let it wait until debugger connected.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly, opening the app and then attaching using Android Studio's attach debugger function, it stops in the desired breakpoints. Which is not the case with the above (Although promising since it stops and waits).

Comment: Worked great for me. I was able to break on something in Application.onCreate()

Comment: One thing to add: `clear-debug-app` to clear the package previous set for debugging with `set-debug-app`.

Answer (score 3):

You can run an app with a debugger directly attachted to it at startup by using this little button:

[image: Android Studio menu bar]

Comment: This seems to only catch breakpoints running the the same process as the application.  The breakpoints I'm trying to catch are in a Service that is configured to run in a remote process (i.e. remote attribute in the manifest is set to the name of the process).